# Docker - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - Image installation path overwriting a volume - changes not reflected

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to sort this permission error on Ubuntu, when trying to run my containers using `dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

```
Exiting
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:433:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/api/limpar/current/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EACCES)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV NODE_VERSION 12
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV INSTALL_PATH /home/api/limpar/current

.
(...)

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . $INSTALL_PATH

RUN rm -rf tmp

RUN useradd -Ms /bin/bash api -u 1001
RUN chown -R api:api /home/api /usr/local/bundle
USER api


EXPOSE 3000
CMD rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    api:
      container_name: limpar-api
      image: limpar-api
      build: .
      command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
      env_file:
        - .env
      volumes:
        - ./:/home/api/limpar/current
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      networks:
        - limpar_network
```

`docker build` runs with no failures. `Dockerfile` instal_path overwrites a volume location on `docker-compose` file. By changing the volume name on my docker-compose.yml file,
`I am able to fix the permission errors.`

However, the local changes on my code no longer get reflected, meaning I have to rebuild everytime I change anything.

Any missing points on Dockerfile, regarding user permissions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
USER root
```

to Docker file, `RUN chown...` fixed the permission issues, and allowed me to keep same path on dockerfile and docker-compose volume, solving the local code changes not reflecting.